# When creating a new record in Rails 3 get the value of field in previous record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I am trying to get the value of a form field of the previous record when creating a new record.

Basically each record has a text area for notes. When creating a new record, instead of the notes field containing a static value or being blank, I would like it to pull the value of this field from the previously created record.

For example the parent model is Customer and the child model is called Stickies.

I have tried this by calling:

```
@customer.stickies.last.notes
```

When you do this everything is `nil`. I assume this is because when calling this in the view it assumes the last record is actually the record that is about to be saved. Anyone know how I can accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `@last_note = @customer.stickies.last.notes` before creating a new record and use this value to show last note.

Comment: That worked, I was assigning the value after building the new resource so that seems to be why it didn't work. Thankss!